# Fckeditor in drupal 7

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I have installed WYSIWYG module in my drupal website and i unziped  fckeditor folder in libraries directory.
In 'Wysiwyg profile' page i set fckeditor for Filtered html format then checked all the button i want to display on the editor.

in the Filtered html configuration page i enabled:
1- Limit allowed HTML tags, and i allowed all the tags i need to use.
2- Convert line breaks into HTML
3- Convert URLs into links 
4- Correct faulty and chopped off HTML

Now when editing or create new node the fckeditor appear after finishing and saving the node the text display like this:

[b]Services

1- [/b][u][b]Civil and Electromechanical Contracting for O&G Companies[/b][/u][b]

[u]Construction of sewer pipelines, and waste water treatment plants
Construction o[i]f unpaved r[/i]oads (service roads)
Warehouses & buildings construction
Water wells drilling, uphole and dynamite drilling for geophysical surveys
Electromechanical construction[/u]

2- Foundation & Soil Shoring Systems Contracting
[i]
Geotechnical Investigation
Foundations and soil shoring systems design and execution
Ground treatment and improvement
3- Mining Services
[/i]
Drilling, blasting, crushing, and transport of minerals

[/b]

notice: i set some text as h3 and i colored some words but nothing appear as i want.
Please help

Comment: I have found the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor to be much more dev friendly and you can integrate your styles into the editor very easily, more info: http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: Thanks for your comment but i need fckeditor to work